# SSD wearout (Lenovo laptop)

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bsod

My laptop crashed today to a point that something switched in bios and Windows wasn't first in line.
I run Lenovo Diagnostics on my SSD and got "passed" for all tests and a note under SMART Wearout Test: *Your SSD is getting close to its wearout limit. Lenovo recommends  you continue to monitor this*.

Should I be concerned? How long does my SSD have?

Answer (score 1):

How concerned you should be depends entirely on how fresh your backup is.

If you are backing up hourly, then you can afford to wait until the drive dies, knowing the most work you can lose is an hour.

If you have no backup, now would be the time to start.